# Regarding if statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I've seen some PHP statements that go something like

```
 if($variable) {} or
 if(function()) {} (if statements that don't compare two variables)
```

and I know they roughly mean if a function executes or if this variable exists but I can't seem to find any information on how they work specifically. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Does PHP have [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)?

Comment: the latest 5.3 does => http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php. I have never seen the in if statements by the way in any language...

Comment: I'm an old fogey (in internet years), and PHP *does not*, er, does have anonymous functions as of 5.3.0.

Comment: with function() do you mean a generic func(); or the reserved word function ?

Comment: @Alfred - You do realize that was the link I had in my original comment?

Comment: @yes123 - What is the difference?

Comment: @Jared I did not realize that.. I also don't believe you had that in beginning and edited your question 6 minutes ago..

Comment: @Alfred - I did edit my *comment* (I am not the OP), but it was almost immediately after I posted my comment. Either way, it doesn't matter. I'm old school. :)

Comment: @Alfred - Anonymous functions in PHP is like plastic wrap on a sailboat. I guess I just don't get it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if(function()) {}` means if the function **function**'s return value is true or [true-like](http://php.net/boolean) then the block will execute.

Answer (score 2):

If a variable is equal to a number which is not zero, that's considered as true.
as well as if the function returns a positive/negative number which is different from 0.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php):

> if (expr)
>    statement
>
> As described in the section about
>   expressions, expression is evaluated
>   to its Boolean value. If expression
>   evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute
>   statement, and if it evaluates to
>   FALSE - it'll ignore it.

So, if a function successfully runs (true) or a variable exists (true) the if statement will continue. Otherwise it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The if statements determine whether the given variable is true or a given function returns true.  A variable is considered "true" if it isn't null, false, 0, or (perhaps) an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

When PHP evaluates if statements, it is determining whether or not the contents are true. It considers anything other than 0 to be true, and 0 to be false. This means you can put a function in there that returns anything and based on that it will determine whether or not to execute the contents of the if block.

Answer (score 1):

something that may help. You are probably thinking of something like if ($variable < 10), or if ($variable == 'some value'). Just like +, -, /, *, and % these are operators. 1 + 3 returns a value of 4 which is used in the rest of a standard statement. 1 < 3 returns a value of *false* which is used in the rest of the statement. the if-method accepts a boolean parameter, and executes code if that boolean parameter is true.

notice that:

```
if (1 < 3) { ... }
```

is the same as

```
$myComparison = 1 < 3;
if ($myComparison) { ... }
```