# if statement with just one variable as conditionals-php

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to study php and I came across a if statement which has a single variable as a conditional like this:

```
<?php if($a){
//do something
}
?>;
```

I know some C++ and javascript, but in those languages, this if statement would ben invalid. Could anyone tell me what this if statement means?

Comment: if `$a` has a trutly value in  it the if statement is true ([**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php))

Comment: Those other languages have similar mechanisms for evaluating a single variable as truthy or falsey, that is for variables which are not booleans. Each language has its own specific rules on what evaluates to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

As Rizier123 said above, the conditional is checking for "Truthy" values in the variable $a. 
In a loosely-typed language like PHP, a truthy value is anything that is a non-empty, non-NULL, or non-zero value.

See this great answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693908/2796449
or the PHP docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Boolean logic always reduces down the entire statement down to one value, either TRUE or FALSE. So executing something like "echo (3==4);" will show FALSE. Similarly if your variable returns a truthy value, it will be evaluated as TRUE.

These 3 are all comparable statements:

$a = 1;
if ( $a )

if ( 1 )

if ( TRUE )