# Create and echo a string from integers in database with php

Tags: php, mysql, string, int, echo

I select a column 'status' from my db that holds 3 ints. i will want the 0,1,2 to echo hello, goodbye, whatever to the user once they are on the page.

```
0 = hello
1= goodbye
2= whatever
```

i cant find any examples of how you echo this with php.

Ive seen loads of examples that just give cold code for $var = 1  $var= hello... etc .  I  cant see how this fits into a real example.

So far i select the column and the status will echo but with a 1 in front of staus 0 and a 1 at end of status 1 .

```
echo "<td>".( $row["status"]==0 ?  : 'Hello' ). ( $row["status"]==1 ?  : 'Goodbye' ) ."</td>";
```

Table result

```
Status:
hello1
hello1
hello1
1goodbye
hello1
1goodbye
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array to hold the various options that it can be.  It almost acts like a small lookup table, but saves linking to another database table...

```
$options = [ 0 => "hello", 1 => "goodbye", 2 => "whatever" ];
$row["status"] = 1;

echo "<td>". $options[$row["status"]]."</td>";
```

gives...

```
<td>goodbye</td>
```

Comment: nice one this seems to work.   $row["status"] = 1;   i removed the =1 and it takes the int and converts to the string nicely .

Comment: i cant ask any more questions on stack...was this question that bad?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with it or why you can't ask questions. You can ask on meta.stackoverflow.com if there is a problem and they may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

PHP switch statement:

```
switch ($row["status"]) {
    case 0: $var = "hello"; break;
    case 1: $var = "goodbye"; break;
    case 2: $var = "whatever"; break;
}
```

full example:

```
$str = "<td>";
switch ($row["status"]) {
    case 0: $str .= "hello"; break;
    case 1: $str .= "goodbye"; break;
    case 2: $str .= "whatever"; break;
}
$str .= "</td>";
echo $str;
```

Or you could do a case statement in your mysql:

```
SELECT status,
CASE
    WHEN status = 1 THEN "Hello"
    WHEN status = 2 THEN "Goodbye"
    WHEN status = 3 THEN "Whatever"
END
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: iam gettign an error,     echo "<td>". switch( $row["status"]) {
            case 0: $var = "hello"; break;
            case 1: $var = "goodbye"; break;
            case 2: $var = "whatever"; break;
}. "</td>";

Comment: I don't think you can use switch statements in line like that, I edited for a better example

Comment: great the php one worked nicely . Thanks for the full example..thats where i get lost normally

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing what you currently have, because you are using a [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator), you need to use it correctly. Also need to be aware that checking ==1 checks for [truthiness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693876/how-exactly-does-ifvariable-work) and not for 1, and so 2 also would match, so change to use === instead:

Change to this:

```
echo "<td>". ( $row["status"]===0 ? 'Hello' : '' ) . ( $row["status"]===1 ? 'Goodbye' : '' ) . ( $row["status"]===2 ? 'Whatever' : '' ) . "</td>";
```

Comment: i see what it was doing now..   trouble is the answer is concatenated and i need a different word for each number.. i.e there will only be 1 number in each table row.

Comment: Using $row["status"] === 0 ?: "Hello" is valid. It just won't do anything if its false

Comment: @MattAltepeter won't do anything if it is true