# How to exclude a parameter within an if statement?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create somewhat of a fuzzy search with PHP. Consider the following pseudo code/scenario below.

Take these `$_POST`ed values:

```
name
price
location
age
```

And I have an array of items (lets assume cars), of which each item contains the following properties:

```
name
price
location
age
```

So in my function, I use an `if()` within a `foreach()` to check if any of the posted data matches with an item and if it does, echo the item.

```
function search() {

 $items = array(...);

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $price = $_POST['price'];
 $location = $_POST['location'];
 $age = $_POST['age'];

 foreach($items as $item) {
   if(
    $item['name']  ==  $name &&
    $item['price'] == $price &&
    $item['location'] == $location &&
    $item['age'] == $age
    ){
      echo json_encode($item);
    } 

 }

}
```

The issue is that not every posted value is filled in, so for example `$name` could be empty i.e. `$name = ''`.

**Question:** How can I exclude any of the items in the `if()` statement if the initial `$_post`ed key is empty without creating an `if()` inception type scenario? I considered using `||` but I'm pretty sure that wouldn't be the same as excluding a comparison all together. A

Comment: Rather than simply vote to close it for 'being unclear' - take the time to comment as to why you think it is unclear - because it's literally unclear why you find it 'unclear'. And to be honest, I believe I explained it pretty clearly hence a prompt answer and an upvote of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by taking advantage of PHP's [lazy interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
if(
    (!$name || ($name && $item['name']  ==  $name)) &&
    (!$price || ($price && $item['price'] == $price)) &&
    (!$location || ($location && $item['location'] == $location)) &&
    (!$age || ($age && $item['age'] == $age))
    ){
      echo json_encode($item);
    }
```

This will first check that each variable is not null, nor empty. ([How exactly does if($variable) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693876/how-exactly-does-ifvariable-work))
Also look at [Does PHP have short-circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/does-php-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: This is right. Alternative would be 4 if's with error counter. I think.