# if condition with one variable for understanding

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regarding if statements in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554384/regarding-if-statements-in-php)

this is a simple question. But Here I need to know how if condition work with only one variable.

```
$category='';

if ($category) {

}
```

can you tell what actually check in If condition? Condition has only one variable..

is it checking variable is TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: Yes It is checking TRUE or FALSE. If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it.

Comment: _Every_ expression is (sooner or later) evaluatable to a boolean value and `if` expects one ;)

Comment: Thanks for all answers... I understood clearly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a [weak typed language](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). To understand what is evaluated in the `if` condition, see the [conversion rules for booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Quoting from the manual:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:
>
> - the boolean `FALSE` itself
> - the integer `0` (zero)
> - the float `0.0` (zero)
> - **the empty string**, and the string `"0"`
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)
> - `SimpleXML` objects created from empty tags

Therefore, your condition will be evaluated as `FALSE`, since `$category == ''` and `(bool) '' === FALSE`

Answer (score 2):

### Type 1

```
$category = '';
if ($category) {
   echo 'category';
} else {
   echo 'no category';
}
```

// Output : no category

### Type 2

```
$category = TRUE;
if ($category) {
   echo 'category';
} else {
   echo 'no category';
}
```

// Output : category

### Type 3

```
$category = '';
if (!empty($category)) {
   echo 'category';
} else {
   echo 'no category';
}
```

// Output : no category

### Type 4

```
$category = 0;
if (!empty($category)) {
   echo 'category';
} else {
   echo 'no category';
}
```

// Output : no category

### Type 5

```
$category = 0;
if (isset($category)) {
   echo 'category';
} else {
   echo 'no category';
}
```

// Output : category

Answer (score 1):

this will check for `TRUE`

```
if ($category) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You empty string will be casted to a boolean value, `false` in this case. See the [`manual on Booleans`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Answer (score 1):

This checks whether variable evaluates to `true`, it's an equivalent of:

```
if( (bool)$category === true) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is checking TRUE or FALSE. If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

if ($category) {

}

Will simply check if $category has a value. You did not give $category a value.
In this case, it will give a FALSE.

Comment: Not true, example: `$category = '0'`. It has a value but `if($category)` will still evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The block of the if-condition activates whenever the evaluated statement is true.

The empty string in PHP evaluates to false, so this will not be activated. You could be more specific by specifying what you expect, for example:

```
   $category = '';
   if (empty($category)) {

   }
```

... in case you expect this to activate whenever it is empty. It really depends on what you are trying to to but like this I assume the condition is never met.