# What does if($array) condition mean in php?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

What does `if ($array){ }` condition mean in php?

When is it true or false?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding if statements in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554384/regarding-if-statements-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array will be casted to a boolean, like if you would use `if((bool) $array) { }`

`false` is returned when the array is empty (e.g. `$array = []`)

`true` is returned as soon as at least one key is set in the array (either like `["some value"]` or `["data" => "value"]`

You can simply test what the returned value will be by using

`var_dump((bool) $your_array);`